# How to find alternating repetitive digit pair?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

`121426` <- Here, 1 is an alternating repetitive digit.

`523563` <- Here, NO digit is an alternating repetitive digit.

`552523` <- Here, both 2 and 5 are alternating repetitive digits.

`333567` <- Here, 3 is an alternating repetitive digit.

I found `re.findall(r'(?=(\d)\d\1)',P)` as the solution in editorial but not able to understand it.

Edit - Not allowed to use `if` conditions.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of why `(?=(\d)\d\1)` matches or are you accepting a different answer ?

Comment: While this `(?=(\d)\d\1)` doesn't _consume_ anything, it stores the digit you need in group 1. And since the engine didn't consume anything, it does a _bump along_ of the current position. This is standard regex behavior, and is more the answer you should have looked for.

Comment: I want to undestand the explanation of `(?=(\d)\d\1)` and also to know other ways by which it can be solved.

Comment: I just explained how  `(?=(\d)\d\1)` works, and you accepted another way. So there you go. Both are overlap substring matching, one more than the other. The _bump along_ occurs only with one, not the other.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html] in explaination of `?=` it is mentioned that "(?=...) Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov' " but in `(?=(\d)\d\1)` there is nothing in front of `?=` to match

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may use this regex using lookaheads:

```
(\d)(?=\d\1)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpdXdl/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(\d)`: Match and capture a digit in group #1
- `(?=`: Start lookahead

  - `\d`: Match any digit
  - `\1`: Back-reference to captured group #1
- `)`: End lookahead

Comment: OP is a bit unclear about this case, but, I think the 3 in `333567` should be matched? It's occurring in alternate pattern.

Comment: Yeah. @VikashYadav, please add this case and the expected output in the question.

Comment: @anubhava, sir can u please explain the editotorial solution?

Comment: I have edited explanation already in my answer. Let me know which part is not clear and I will answer.

Comment: python doc. mentioned that "(?=...)
Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov' " but in `(?=(\d)\d\1)` there is nothing in front of `?=` to match.

Comment: @VikashYadav: You may want to read this tutorial on look-arounds: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 11):

You could do this without a regex using `zip()` in a list comprehension:

```
>>> s = '552523'
>>> [a for a, b in zip(s, s[2:]) if a == b]
['5', '2']
```